# Reverse Sort Months In SSRS & Calculate Variance

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am rather new to SSRS and am struggling with how I can achieve this.

Basically I need to calculate variance between two months, and have achieved this with the use of PREVIOUS() function. Similar to another person who has posted this on another forum.

[image]

However, the user has got back and wanted to sort months by descending, similar to the example shown below. Is there a way to do this in SSRS? As what I have gotten is that the 'previous' column is now referencing a future month and the calculations are now all wrong.

I have tried LOOKUP in SSRS, using DENSE in sql and all does not seem to work.

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a generous sample of the underlying data, preferably in directly useable form? Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following workaround

Sort by month in descending order.

Add a total column.

Hide last month columns.

March will be displayed on February, February on January and January on the total columns

On the total column you will use expressions to display January.

Your design will look like the colored tablix

[image]

Expressions will be like these below

orange:  `=Previous(SUM(Fields!val.Value), "month2")` /* previous value to display it as current */

yellow: `=Sum(Fields!val.Value)` /* current value to diplay it as previous */

green: `=First(Fields!month.Value)`  /* First month of dataset */

cyan: `=ReportItems!val2.value` /* previous cell value to display it as first month */

Result will look like the image below

[image]